# JW Player controlbar.idlehide animation - can it be used to control other divs in the same page?

Tags: html, jwplayer

This is mostly an 'in theory question'.
I have a div with two buttons that I'd like to show/hide on mouseover/out at the same time and with the same trigger area that JW Player controlbar.idlehide uses.

Would something like having both divs named the same work (the div with two buttons named the same as the controlbar div, that JW Player already uses and works) or does the controlbar only work inside video tags? Is there another variable that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

This can only be used to control the controlbar asset of the JW Player itself.